# Python script getting Killed

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, python-unittest

**Environment**
Flask 0.10.1
SqlAlchemy 1.0.10
Python 3.4.3

**Using unittest**

I have created two separate tests whose goals are looking into the databases through 700k records and doing some string finds. When the tests are executed one at a time, it works fine, but when the whole script is executed with:

```
python name_of_script.py
```

it exits with "KILLED" at random places.

The main code on both tests go something like this:

```
def test_redundant_categories_exist(self):
    self.assertTrue(self.get_redundant_categories() > 0, 'There are 0 redundant categories to remove. Cannot test removing them if there are none to remove.')

def get_redundant_categories(self):
        total = 0
        with get_db_session_scope(db.session) as db_session:
            records = db_session.query(Category)
            for row in records:
                if len(row.c) > 1:
                    c = row.c
                    #TODO: threads, each thread handles a bulk of rows
                    redundant_categories = [cat_x.id
                                            for cat_x in c
                                            for cat_y in c
                                            if cat_x != cat_y and re.search(r'(^|/)' + cat_x.path + r'($|/)', cat_y.path)
                                            ]
                    total += len(redundant_categories)
            records = None
            db_session.close()
        return total
```

The other test calls a function located in the `manager.py` file that does something similar, but with an added bulk delete in the database.

```
    def test_remove_redundant_mappings(self):
        import os
        os.system( "python ../../manager.py remove_redundant_mappings" )
        self.assertEqual(self.get_redundant_categories(), 0, "There are redundant categories left after running manager.py remove_redundant_mappings()")
```

Is it possible for the data to be kept in memory between tests? I don't quite understand how executing the tests individually works, but when run back to back, the process ends with Killed.

Any ideas?

**Edit (things I've tried to no avail):**

- import the function from `manager.py` and call it without `os.system(..)`
- `import gc` and run a `gc.collect()` after `get_redundant_categories()` and after calling `remove_redundant_mappings()`

Comment: Using `os.system` is really necessary? It spawn a new process and might cause trouble. Importing `remove_redundant_mappings` via python seems a better idea to start with.

Comment: I did try importing it through from manager import remove_redundant_mappings but during executing it says it can't find the module manager

Comment: You should check your system's log files (you can use `dmesg` if you're on linux). It sounds like the process is being killed by the kernel to protect the system. If you're loading a ton of info into memory, it may be throwing an OOM (Out Of Memory) error in the system logs.

Comment: You might want to add `os.path.join(dirname(__FILE__), '..', '..')` to your 'sys.path` to be able to import. It is not the prettiest line but still better than your `os.system`. Maybe a look at `ps aux | grep python` and `top` (or`htop`) for memory could help debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching high and low, I serendipitously came upon the following comment in this [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720344/sqlalchemy-force-all-connections-to-close-mysql?rq=1)

> What is happening, I think, is that people are instantiating sessions and not closing them. The objects are then being garbage collected without closing the sessions. Why sqlalchemy sessions don't close themselves when the session object goes out of scope has always and will always be beyond me.  @melchoir55

So I added the following the to the method that was being tested:

```
db_session.close()
```

Now the unittest executes without getting killed.